# How to add bundles for parent and child projects into bundle config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I am working with ASP.Net MVC application. I wanted to add bundles in bundle config file for JS and CSS. My application is one of the sub application or sub-project(lets say - menu_1 project) of my main or parent application (lets say Parent project).
So, there are some bundles I need to create, related to parent project inside my child project  (menu_1 project) and some bundles I need to create for the same (menu_1 project) project. And some bundles are combination of both the projects (Parent project and menu_1 project).

I tried to create those bundles but some of the bundles are not loaded while running the application.
So, how we should add js/css file url's in bundles for Parent project of child(menu_1 project) project.